# How can I get a dynamic modal to also map out with my card list?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Whenever my program runs; the cards are displayed on the screen with the correct information. But when I click on the button to open the modal; it displays incorrect information, like the wrong event title or multiple statuses.

My guess is that the cards are actual objects that are being mapped to the screen; but the modal is one entity so it shows whatever is at that point in time. How do I correctly map a modal with my card mapping so I can dynamically show information on the modal about that particular card?

```
class Events extends Component {

state = {
    creating: false
};

startCreateEventHandler = () =>
    this.setState({ creating: true });

modalCancelHandler = () => {
    this.setState({ creating: false });
}

componentDidMount() {
    this.ensureDataFetched();
}

ensureDataFetched() {
    this.props.requestEvents();
}





render() {
    return (
        <div>
        {this.props.events.map(event => 
        <React.Fragment> 
            {this.state.creating &&
                <Modal title="Add Event" canCancel onCancel= 
                   {this.modalCancelHandler}>
                    <p>{event.title}</p>
                    <p>{event.start}</p>
                    <p>{event.ticketRequests.map(request =>
                        request.status)}</p>
                    <p>heyyy</p>

                </Modal>
            }

            <Card color="blue" className="card" style={{ width: '18red' 
}}>
                <CardBody className="card-body">
                    <CardTitle>{event.title}</CardTitle>
                    <CardText>Event Info</CardText>
                    <button className="requestButton" 
                    color="yellow">Request Tickets</button>
                    <button className="claimButton" onClick= 
                    {this.startCreateEventHandler}>Tickets Claimed: 
                    </button>
                </CardBody>
                </Card> 
        </React.Fragment>  

        )}    
        </div>
    );
}  
}
```

Modal File

```
import React from 'react';
import './modal.css';

const modal = props => (
<div className="modal">
    <header className="modal_header">
        <h1>{props.title}</h1>
    </header>
    <section className="modal_content">{props.children}</section>
    <section className="modal_actions">

        {props.canCancel && (
            <button className="btn" onClick={props.onCancel}>
                Cancel
            </button>
        )}
    </section>
</div>

);

export default modal;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is happening here is that you are opening all modals at once.

What you could do is keep in the state the index (or unique id) of each `event` and only render the modal if the index/unique id matches.

```
class Events extends Component {

  state = {
    creatingId: -1
  };

  startCreateEventHandler = creatingId =>
    this.setState({ creatingId });

  modalCancelHandler = () => {
    this.setState({ creatingId: -1 });
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.ensureDataFetched();
  }

  ensureDataFetched() {
    this.props.requestEvents();
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <div>
        {this.props.events.map((event, i) => 
        <React.Fragment> 
            // the best way of doing it is with unique id property, but it also works with index
            // {this.state.creatingId == event.id &&
               {this.state.creatingId == i &&
                <Modal title="Add Event" canCancel onCancel= 
                   {this.modalCancelHandler}>
                    <p>{event.title}</p>
                    <p>{event.start}</p>
                    <p>{event.ticketRequests.map(request =>
                        request.status)}</p>
                    <p>heyyy</p>

                </Modal>
            }

            <Card color="blue" className="card" style={{ width: '18red' }}>
                <CardBody className="card-body">
                    <CardTitle>{event.title}</CardTitle>
                    <CardText>Event Info</CardText>
                    <button className="requestButton" 
                    color="yellow">Request Tickets</button>
                    <button className="claimButton" onClick= 
                    {() => this.startCreateEventHandler(i)}>Tickets Claimed: 
                    </button>
                </CardBody>
                </Card> 
        </React.Fragment>  

        )}    
        </div>
    );     
  }  
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that is a smart way to go about it and it fixed my specific issue!

Comment: I did though notice that my cancel button doesn't work anymore, do you know why this is?

Comment: @Aktzin I made a small mistake, but just fixed, please check my edit

Comment: Could you maybe help me with someone else very similar to what you just did? I'm trying to map that nested 'ticketRequests' array, but the output I consistently get is all of the events instead of that very particular event. I tried to use the eventId key; but I don't believe I did it correctly.

Comment: Disregard last comment, apparently I had set up my variables incorrectly in the API.